# Calling a web service using URL with complex parameters

Tags: asp.net, web-services, parameters

I have web services that work fine using SOAP, but today I received a request to call the web services using the URL.

So, instead of consuming the service, they want to call http://servicename/ProductEnq.asmx/ProductEnqByCodeWithLogin?Code=123456789&Username=user&Password=bubbles

I found that the "basic" calls work 100%, i.e. when the params are all strings, like the call above. This method returns a complex type.

Where I get stuck is that I have another method that expects a List of strings as parameter together with some other params.

No matter how I try to get the list to be populated, the page always returns "System.InvalidOperationException: ProductEnqByMultipleCodesWithLogin Web Service method name is not valid."

Please note that this call works 100% when called from my application or WebService Studio.

Any hints on if this is possible, or should I just convince the client to use SOAP?

Thank you.

Jaco